# Dynamically calling functions - Python

Tags: python

I have a list of functions... e.g.

```
def filter_bunnies(pets): ...

def filter_turtles(pets): ...

def filter_narwhals(pets): ...
```

**Is there a way to call these functions by using a string representing their name?**

e.g.

```
'filter_bunnies', 'filter_turtles', 'filter_narwhals'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Function From a String With the Function's Name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: A little different from the other question, in that the functions to be called here are *so* similar, and likely to be suitable for redesign suggestions that would not be as good a fit for a generic "how to call a function given the function's name as a string"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are your function a part of an object? If so you could use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
>> class A:
    def filter_bunnies(self, pets):
        print('bunnies')

>>> getattr(A(), 'filter_bunnies')(1)
bunnies
```

Comment: This is the right way to go: if they're not already methods of a class, create a dummy Dispatcher class and make them methods of that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use:

```
globals()['filter_bunnies']()
```

to call 'filter_bunnies'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function locals() to get a dictionary of variables and functions, here is an example:

```
def a(str):
    print("A" + str)

def b(str):
    print("B" + str)

def c(str):
    print("C" + str)

for f in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    locals()[f]('hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

My code crystal ball detects that there may be some commonality among your filter functions.  Are they really different functions, or are they all the same with just a single filter value that is different?  If you have substantial repetition in a program, stop and think if it is worth some refactoring into a single common function, which will be much more maintainable than a set of very similar functions.  You could have a single function `filterByType` that takes 2 arguments, the list of pets and the filtering type, and then just define a dict to map input strings to the type object or class that you mean to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

using [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: And the name of the function is `os.removedirs('/');filter_bunnies`.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and ugliest way would be to call it by using eval function, which would evaluate your string. Much cleaner solution is to use getattr function on a module to which function belongs to obtain function's reference, and then call it by reference.

Another way that just occurred to me to obtain function-s reference would be with use of eval function like this `func = eval("filter_bunnies")`

Be careful when you're using eval, especially if the value of eval is dependent on some sort of user input as it could make you execute unwanted/malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I need to dispatch a function call to one of several functions based on a string, I will make the functions elements of a dict.  I've done this, for example, in writing a simple interpreter, where each keyword is implemented by a different function.  You can even use decorators to elegantly take care of the assignments:

```
KEYWORD_FUNCTIONS = {}

def MAKE_KEYWORD( f ):
    KEYWORD_FUNCTIONS[ f.func_name ] = f
    return f

@MAKE_KEYWORD
def KEYWORD_A( arg ):
    print "Keyword A with arg %s" % arg

@MAKE_KEYWORD
def KEYWORD_B( arg ):
    print "Keyword B with arg %s" % arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KEYWORD_FUNCTIONS[ "KEYWORD_A" ]( "first_argument" )
    KEYWORD_FUNCTIONS[ "KEYWORD_B" ]( "second_argument" )
```

Comment: ``globals()`` and ``locals()`` are the built in equivalent of you're KEYWORD_FUNCTIONS

Comment: @Rory: a good point.  The difference, of course, is that `globals()` and `locals()` map everything in your global or local namespace, while my approach lets you selectively map only the functions you are interested in.