# Python string to attribute

Tags: python, attributes

How can I achieve such job:

```
def get_foo(someobject, foostring):
    return someobject.foostring
```

IE:

if I do `get_foo(obj, "name")` it should be calling `obj.name` (see input as string but I call it as an attritube.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically calling functions - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818490/dynamically-calling-functions-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use the builtin function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#getattr).

> **getattr**(*object*, *name*[, *default*])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, *default* is returned if provided, otherwise [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) is raised.

Comment: that's a huge blessing that we can do that =)

Answer (score 54):

If `someobject` has an attribute named `foostring` then

```
def get_foo(someobject, foostring):
    return getattr(someobject,foostring)
```

or if you want to set an attribute to the supplied object then:

```
def set_foo(someobject, foostring, value):
    return setattr(someobject,foostring, value)
```

Try it

Answer (score 37):

You should use setattr and getattr:

```
setattr(object,'property',value)
getattr(object,'property',default)
```