# Python plugin structure - execute code from another file

Tags: python, methods

Let's say I have a folder containing the main-file `main.py` and a configuration-file `config.json`.

In the JSON-file there are multiple entries containing different filenames and the name of a method within each file.

Depending on user input from `main.py` I get the corresponding filename and the method from `config.json` and now I want to execute that method.

I tried the following

```
file = reports [id]["filename"]
method = reports [id]["method"]
# which would give me: file = 'test.py' and method = 'execute'
import file
file.method()
```

This didn't work obviously. The problem is that I can't know which files there are during compilation.

Other developers would add scripts to a specific folder and add their entries to the configuration file (kind of like a plugin). Does anybody have a solution here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Comment: Use the package `importlib`.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253966/python-string-to-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input... importlib was the way to go. I used this answer here:

[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)