# use list to set function and name output in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to use a loop to change the function applied to a DataFrame and name the output in python

For example, I would like to calculate the mean, max,sum, min, etc of the same DataFrame and I'd like to use a loop to cycle through these and name the output.

Say i have a DataFrame df ...

```
numbs = [[ 1,2,4],[34,5,6],[22,4,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(numbs,columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I want to use this calcs dict to define the function applied to df and name the output, like this

```
calcs = {'sum','mean','max'}
for i in calcs:
    ('df'+ i) = df.i
```

And I was looking for output like

```
dfsum
A 57
B 11
C 15

dfmean
A  19.000
B  3.667
C  5.000 

etc
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your attempt at coding this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `agg` with a list of functions:

```
numbs = [[ 1,2,4],[34,5,6],[22,4,5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(numbs,columns=['A','B','C']) 

df_out = df.agg(['mean','max','min'])

print(df_out.loc['mean'])
print(df_out.loc['max'])
print(df_out.loc['min'])
```

You can access each series in the dataframe using index selection with `loc`.

Output:

```
A    19.000000
B     3.666667
C     5.000000
Name: mean, dtype: float64
A    34.0
B     5.0
C     6.0
Name: max, dtype: float64
A    1.0
B    2.0
C    4.0
Name: min, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use set `calcs`, you may use `agg` directly on it as follows:

```
calcs = {'sum','mean','max'}

df.agg(calcs).T.add_prefix('df')

Out[922]:
   dfmax  dfsum     dfmean
A   34.0   57.0  19.000000
B    5.0   11.0   3.666667
C    6.0   15.0   5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Without *strings*, you can do simply:

```
calcs = {pd.DataFrame.sum, pd.DataFrame.mean, pd.DataFrame.max}
# or even with the builtins: {sum, pd.DataFrame.mean, max}
for calc in calcs:
    df.apply(calc)
```

If you require to use strings, then [use the builtin `getattr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253966/python-string-to-attribute):

```
calcs = {'sum', 'mean', 'max')
for calc in calcs:
    getattr(df, calc)()
```