# Pass class method name as a parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the last line of following code

```
import io
import pandas as pd

writer = io.BytesIO()
data = [{"createdAt": 2021, "price": 10}, {"createdAt": 2022, "price": 20} ]
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(self.writer, header="true", index=False)
```

so that I can pass the name of the class method `to_csv` as an argument.

Like

```
f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(data).x(self.writer, header="true", index=False)
f('to_csv') # should do exactly the same as pd.DataFrame(data).x(.....
```

I tried `to_csv`, `to_csv()` as an argument as well. May I ask for help for fixing this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code for your class?

Comment: Just to mention that `f = lambda...` is against PEP8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python string to attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253966/python-string-to-attribute) and [How to access (get or set) object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612610/4046632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)?

```
f = lambda x: getattr(pd.DataFrame(data), x)(self.writer, header=True, index=False)
f('to_csv')
```

Or with a function:

```
def f(x):
    return getattr(pd.DataFrame(data), x)(self.writer, header=True, index=False)
f('to_csv')
```